# replace wrongly spelled words,python

Tags: python, replace, tuples, func

I have a set of tuples of the form

```
ref_set = [(a1,b1),(a2,b2),(a3,b3)...]
```

and so on. I need to compare words from a list of sentences and check if it is equal to `a1`, `a2`, `a3`.. if `word == a1`, replace it with `b1`. If `word == a2`, replace with `b2` and so on.

Here's my code:

```
def replace_words(x): #function
    for line in x: #iterate over lines in list
        for word in line.split(): #iterate over words in list
            for i,j in ref_set: #iterate over each tuple
                if word == i: #if word is equal to first element
                   word = j  #replace it with 2nd one.
```

I'm getting `None` as a result; I know I need to return something.

Comment: Your indentation was wrong and I fixed it. It seems dumb, but maybe that was your error...?

Comment: @henrebotha: It is commonly seen in Python posts by beginners not familiar with how you can use the editor to indent code blocks. By just adding spaces to the first line of the block the code looks like it was marked up correctly..

Comment: @henrebotha error is `word = j` he don't change list but change value of `word`

Comment: Sword Can you have list like: `[(a1, b1), (a1, b2)]` ? I think no..

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: A list of tuples is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a list of tuples. Use a dictionary:

```
ref_map = dict(ref_set)

for line in x:
    line = ' '.join([ref_map.get(word, word) for word in line.split()])
```

otherwise you have a NxM loop; for every extra word in your text or in your `ref_set` you *double* the number of iterations you need to do.

Your code only rebinds `word`, not replace the word in the `line`; the list comprehension above produces a new `line` value instead. This doesn't replace the line in `x` though, you need another list comprehension for that:

```
x = [' '.join([ref_map.get(word, word) for word in line.split()]) for line in x]
```

It appears from the comments that `x` is not a list of sentences but rather *one* sentence. In which case you use just process that one line with one list comprehension, as in the loop iteration over `x` above:

```
def corrected(line):
    return ' '.join([ref_map.get(word, word) for word in line.split()])
```

Comment: thanks martin . i guess i'm having a problem. check the image above. no_punc is my original data and after applying ur code , i got the next column . i used def corrected(x) followed by  x = [' '.join([ref_map.get(word, word) for word in line.split()]) for line in x] and then "return(x)" . how could that be solved. ? sorry ,i'm a beginner so i wasnt able to explain well.

Comment: @Sword: `x` is supposed to be a list of strings, not a string.

Comment: yes . but i'm applying it on a dataframe object using data.apply(corrected) {corrected is my function] . check the image. i guess the code is taking each individual letter . sorry again , my bad..!!

Comment: @Sword: Yes, because `x` is one string, not a list of strings. Instead of the loop over `x`, just treat `x` as `line` and use: `def corrected(line): return ' '.join([ref_map.get(word, word) for word in line.split()])`

Comment: could u edit and add the code in your comment ,plz..?

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 10: expected string, long found . what does this mean?

Comment: @Sword: My code works for *strings* and a dictionary `ref_map` that only has string keys and values in it. If any of your `ref_set` tuples have a `bx` value that is *not* a string you'd get that error message.

Comment: @Sword: In other words, you have a `(ax, bx)` pair in `ref_set` that points to a number and not a string.

Comment: is there a way to generalize it to other values as well like numerics etc?

Comment: What do you expect the outcome to be? This is supposed to be a spelling correction, right? So what would returing `10` instead of a string **mean** here? The `str.join()` method can join strings only.

Comment: numbers remain the same , so (ax,bx) might contain (25/4 , 25/4). It corrects the spellings of words but as far as numeric type objects are concerned , it maps them to the same value.

Comment: my dataframe consists of addresses, so there are mixed type objects present.. if the above code doesnt work , could the code present in the question be modified to make it work??

Comment: @Sword: No, you have a `ax` that is a string mapping to a number; each word is looked up in `ref_map` as a key (where `ax`s are keys), and if it is found, the corresponding `bx` is used, otherwise the original `word` is used. That's what the `ref_map.get(word, word)` call does. This would *never* find a `(25/4, 25/4)` number pair, as `word` is always a string.

Comment: thanx, is there a way you could suggest? a method that will do it irrespective of the type of object?

Comment: @Sword: Is asked you what you expect to happen; you cannot just 'make it work' without defining what 'work' means.

Comment: i have made a tuple with the wrong word and the correctly spelled word(using peter norvig and many other different conditions) . so accordingly , when a particular wrong word is found in the address , it needs to be compared with the list of tuples. in case it matches, it will be replaced by the second element of the tuple(which is the corrected word) . i have mapped numbers to numbers itself. The image showed each address where i had to check each word and replace it. your code works , but the problem is when it comes to other types. any suggestions??

Comment: @Sword: Sorry, I think I cannot help you here. I understand what you are trying to do, but it appears you don't understand what I am asking or understand the data structures involved here. You have *at least one* pair in `ref_set` that maps a word to a number, but cannot tell me if that is a mistake or has a different meaning. You'll need to clarify this before we can continue.

Comment: No , a word is not mapped to a number but yes a combination of word and number is present. like((ax,bx) can be(meadows32,meadows32) .. sorry to disturb you :(

Comment: @Sword: The error message you get can **only** be thrown if you do have a `('meadows', 32)` pair in your set. This is what I am trying to tell you, you have *at least one* such pair.